# Adding ScriptManager makes Request never complete

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a very strange problem. Initially, my page is working fine, if I click a "Back" button, it will navigate to the previous page. But when I add this line

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Everything seems to stop working. Clicking the button causes the request to never complete (i.e. I cannot go back to previous page when I click "Back" button).

My page structure looks like this

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master/Main.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="dsp_FileName.aspx.cs" Inherits="[Namespace].dsp_FileName" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Master/Main.Master" %>
<asp:Content ID="C1" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ...
    </script>

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs because in my master page, I have the following snippet:

```
<form id="frmMain" runat="server" onsubmit="progressStart('Please wait...');">
```

Basically I wanted to block any other input when user clicks a button. So I need to modify the above snippet to be :

```
<form id="frmMain" runat="server" onsubmit="progressStart('Please wait...'); return true;">
```

And in the page where I need to use the Script Manager, I need to add the following code.

```
function pageLoad() {
    if (args.get_isPartialLoad()) {                
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../../JS/Javascript.js",  
            dataType: "script",
            cache: true
        });
        $('#dErr').dialog('destroy'); // this is the dialog that will show inside the progressStart function.
    }
}
```